# Typescript enforce function return type to be key of interface based on parameter

Tags: typescript, function, generics, key

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to enforce function to return a correct type based on the key passed to the function. So if the key is `service1` the correct return type should be `Payloads['service1']`. How can I achieve this?

```js
interface Payloads {
    service1: {
        a: boolean;
    };
    service2: {
        b: string;
    };
    service3: {
        c: number;
    };
};

const createPayload = <S extends keyof Payloads>(key: S): Payloads[S] => {
    switch (key) {
        case 'service1': return { a: true }
        case 'service2': return { b: 'e' }
        case 'service3': return { c: 3 }
        default: throw new Error('undefined service')
    }
}
```

Error I get:

[image: error]

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmAzsgN4BQylyh0AbsEgIwBcpFVHcrARjjlhDggA3O0oBfURxpR6SAEytyHDt1aEwUUAHMpVSWOp0GEAMxLDHBKxABXALbdoeiaINkEOEBuQIogyHRsPHxkAF5kAB4AZWQIAA9IECJkAGsIDBwYNExcAkIAPgAKdIxWaIBKViC8ogBtaIBdcIK2aQB3YDAEAAtkEoyKtpVKBDgaZAByGTkIRknWfzBbKBBSZC5kTVsUcUsqMYnp4wUF5CWVtZJkNSmISeQ9kdHxlGPZE1Mzi9X162RTI99pR8BB4LYsGBWGAelAcO1kCAIAiAKJQOFQIqTWzJMGgCChGYmSYVQx7PZAA)

Comment: Note that your question as asked is "why does this error", and not "how do I fix it".  The answer to the question as asked is "because the compiler cannot narrow generic type parameters like `S` via control flow analysis, and so the compiler errs on the side of being conservative as per [ms/TS#30769](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769)". If you also want a way to do it via refactoring for type safety, you might want to [edit] the question to say so explicitly.

Comment: On that note, if you're looking for an alternative approach that maintains type safety, you could refactor to index into an object like [this](//tsplay.dev/mq582m).  Does that meet your needs?  If so, I can write up an answer (assuming the question is edited to ask for such an answer).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz can you provide a reference that explains why that object indexing solves the problem please?

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer has that information (you can read at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types also)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `Payloads[S]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that depends on an as-yet unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `S`.

In your implementation, the compiler is unable to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the type parameter `S` in the `switch`/`case` statement.  It sees that `key` can be narrowed to, for example, `"service1"`, but it does not narrow the type parameter `S`.  And therefore it doesn't know that `{ a: true }` will be assignable to `Payloads[S]` in that circumstance.  The compiler is essentially being too cautious here; the only thing it would be happy returning is a value which is assignable to `Payloads[S]` no matter what `S` is, which turns out to be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all the value types, equivalent to `{a: boolean; b: string; c: number}`.  Since you never return a value like this, the compiler complains.

There are several open issues in GitHub asking for some improvement here.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for example.  For now, though (as of TS4.6), if you must write code that works this way, then the compiler won't help you verify type safety.  You will need to take over the responsibility by using something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

```
const createPayloadAssert = <S extends keyof Payloads>(key: S): Payloads[S] => {
    switch (key) {
        case 'service1': return { a: true } as Payloads[S]
        case 'service2': return { b: 'e' } as Payloads[S]
        case 'service3': return { c: 3 } as Payloads[S]
        default: throw new Error('undefined service')
    }
}
```

or a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```
function createPayloadOverload<S extends keyof Payloads>(key: S): Payloads[S];
function createPayloadOverload(key: keyof Payloads) {
    switch (key) {
        case 'service1': return { a: true };
        case 'service2': return { b: 'e' };
        case 'service3': return { c: 3 };
        default: throw new Error('undefined service')
    }
}
```

to loosen things enough to prevent the error. This necessarily allows you to make mistakes where you accidentally switch around the return values.  But for now that's the best you can do with `switch`/`case`.

---

If you are willing to refactor your implementation to a form where the compiler can actually verify the safety of your code, you can do it by indexing into an object:

```
const createPayload = <S extends keyof Payloads>(key: S): Payloads[S] => ({
    service1: { a: true },
    service2: { b: 'e' },
    service3: { c: 3 }
}[key]);

const createPayloadBad = <S extends keyof Payloads>(key: S): Payloads[S] => ({
    service1: { a: true },
    service2: { a: true }, // <-- error!
    service3: { c: 3 }
}[key]);
```

This works because, among other things, indexed access types were [introduced to TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) (called "lookup types" in that link) in order to represent *at the type level* what happens when you index into an object with a key *at the value level*. That is, if you have an object-like value `t` of type `T`, and a key-like value `k` of type `K`, then when indexing into `t` with `k` like `t[k]`, the property you read will be of type `T[K]`.  So if you want the compiler to know that you have a value of type `Payloads[S]`, you can do so by indexing into a value of type `Payloads` with a key of type `S`, as shown above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-UGI2dXqxdwhSxMq3WEE28I++0OxxcKhDCzDT0j0fen1Y8x+f0TVnBKceZlhUbeCNYyIMU0oOLxBKJJLJFKpyFp9MZzLrbI5qZ+vI4-MFnm8vmt0ttsoIsQSyTSGSyWsKHvKzoNjSnrQ6XVG3sofZYuzjUCOfwANIY+4pdl8c79xBfpMXzBWkX8BS1qu06qIRz5ouOMpAvgABC05xCq87qoubrLpuq76sg9QbsBGKdDE3QVHunLLIesZEiexyPj6xbXvhByEeeyAAPTUQkAC09EpHSOBQAAhJez5KH4lbvuIn55N+ohAA)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't know the type of `S` in the body of the function, so it expects you to pass *all* properties to make sure `Payloads[S]` is fulfilled. But you can trick TypeScript! By changing the return type to `Payloads[keyof Payloads]` it means *one of the options*, and you don't get any error.

Now this has changed the public method signature, but we don't want that. To make this work we have to use `function` declarations, because they allow *overloads*. We are going to add *one* overload to the function, which is the old signature:

```
function createPayload<S extends keyof Payloads>(key: S): Payloads[S];
function createPayload<S extends keyof Payloads>(key: S): Payloads[keyof Payloads] {
    // code here...
}
```

This exposes `Payloads[S]` to the caller, but internally we expect `Payloads[keyof Payloads]`. A full working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmAzsgN4BQylyh0AbsEgIwBcpFVHcrARjjlhDggA3O0oBfURxpR6SAEytyHDt1aEwUUAHMpVSWOp0GEAMxLDHBKxABXALbdoeiaINkYtkAjDAcIZAQoQUh0bDx8AB4AZWQIAA9IECJkAGsIDBwYNExcAkIAPgAKdIxWaIBKVjC8ogBtaIBdUU9vX39A4LhQ3IiYuMSIZOJSrJzw-OLS8qrx2sI60eyaiMJGtmkAd2AwBAALZBKMio2VSgQ4GmQAchk5CEZr1mCwWygAkmQuZE1bFHFLFQLldbsYFE9kC83h9kGobhBrsgAWdzpcUKDZCZTBCoe9SIFWKYkYDKPgIPBbFgwKwwHsoDhNsgQBBGQBRKD0qBFa5eMkwUAQfBGTFIa4VQwAgFAA).

Comment: But you have lost a bit of safety: `case 'service2': return { c: 3 }` is now accepted

Comment: That is true, but I don't know any other way of doing it. I think it's just not possible with TypeScript.

Comment: I agree with @AndreaSimoneCosta the compiler now allows returning an object with all properties combined, whereas what I want to do is explicitly "tell" the compiler to accept only one type from the `Payloads` interface.